# When are data bindings applied?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

At what time of object lifecycle are bindings resolved for the first time?

It is a simple question but I cannot find any information neither in books nor through Google.

Comment: Agree that's the tricky one, I am changing from events to data binding in my custom control and everything falls apart now :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that simple actually, you won't get a straight answer for this question. It depends on the context.

Here are two simple examples :

If the bounded property is owned by a WPF control that is not inside a ControlTemplate, the binding will most likely be resolved for the first time when the [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx) method is called for the first time, if the DataContext is already set.
If the DataContext was not set, it will try to be resolved after the control is Loaded: see the DataBindEngine.RequestRun() below

```
private void RequestRun()
{
    base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new DispatcherOperationCallback(this.Run), false);
    base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new DispatcherOperationCallback(this.Run), true);
}
```

If the bounded property is owned by a WPF control that is inside a ControlTemplate however, it will be resolved for the first time during the first layouting pass that will trigger an [ApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx) and lead to resolving the binding.

Those are only specific examples, if you want to fully understand the binding mechanisms, you should use reflector to take a look at `MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine` and `System.Windows.Data.BindindExpression` classes. Those are the classes responsible for pushing the correct data when using bindings on dependency properties.